# findById() returning null

Tags: aem

Below is my code for dialog, I am trying to get the textfield via id but not able to do so inside the beforesubmit listener. Normally i require to find the particular widget at particular level, so if possible provide some explanation.

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    title="dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tab1
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Tab 1">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <textfield
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        itemId="textfield1"
                        xtype="textfield"/>
                    <selectbox
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        itemId="selectbox1"
                        name="./selectvalue"
                        type="select"
                        xtype="selection">
                        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                            <one
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="one"
                                value="one"/>
                            <two
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="two"
                                value="two"/>
                            <three
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                text="three"
                                value="three"/>
                        </options>
                    </selectbox>
                </items>
            </tab1>
        </items>
    </items>
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        beforesubmit="function(dialog){&#xa;console.log(dialog);&#xa;var item = dialog.findById(&quot;textfield1&quot;);&#xa;console.log(item);&#xa;}"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component with **[itemId](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog#CQ.Dialog-itemId)** can be retrived only with `getComponent()` method of `CQ.Ext.Container`. Dialog is not a sub class of `CQ.Ext.Container`. Here's an excerpt from the docs regarding this :

> An itemId can be used as an alternative way to get a reference to a component when no object reference is available. Instead of using an id with CQ.getCmp, use itemId with CQ.Ext.Container.getComponent which will retrieve itemId's or id's.

`findById()` is used to find components with **[id](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog#CQ.Dialog-id)** and not **itemId**.

Tabpanel in your dialog is a decendant of `CQ.Ext.Container` type. If you want to use itemId to get reference you should first get reference to it and then use `getComponent()` method on it.

```
var tab = dialog.findByType('TabPanel')[0]; //returns an array so taking the first element
var textfield = tab.getComponent('textfield1');
```

Since the fields in the dialog are fixed and you know you are looking for the first textfield, you can directly do

```
var textfield = dialog.findByType('textfield')[0]; // need not deal with id's at all.
```